# How to manage different environments with a single server?

Tags: php, apache, server, development-environment, production-environment

I'm a bit new to these stuffs so pardon my ignorance.

I am working on a web application and i have 4 environments; development, testing, staging and production. and i have only 1 server.

I would like to know what is the best way to manage these 3 environments on 1 server which i guess should be as follows:
- Production can be accessible to everyone
- testing and staging should be accessible to only certain users.

So how would you guys manage these environments?

I was thinking about allowing from a list of ips in my virtual hosts but the users might not have a static ip address.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Apache allows to set envirnoment variable on base of conditions like `request uri` or `ip` etc in apache conf or .htaccess file have a look at `setenvif` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif

Comment: Could you give an example how can i use it in my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If you have four different environments you'll need to set up four different instances of your application - as you're not going to always have the same code running under development, testing, staging and production.

With Apache you can use name based virtual hosts to set up subdomains and point them at each different environment. If you have a control panel on the server, it should handle the creation of subdomains for you. If you need one try Vesta CP - it's free.

You can use code and configuration in your application or security directives on the server to control access to the different environments. One common way of doing this is to use trusted IP addresses but be careful here - you can run into security issues trusting this field - make sure you're very careful trusting (or just don't trust) the value of the X-Forwarded-For header (used by proxies). This very website had an access breach to it's development environment by doing exactly that (google: anatomy of an attack how I hacked stackoverflow, I can't post any more links).

If you use an application framework such as symfony2, you will find that it's control of environments and firewalls can really come into its own in these scenarios.

Here is the documentation for mastering and creating environments: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html

And here is the link to their security recipes: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/index.html

Using the documentation there you should be able to create environment specific security configurations.

Comment: I am using Yii2 ans to create multiple environments is not an issue.. Neither are the virtual hosts..

But the issue is how to handle it and make testing and staging be like invisible to the world. Is it possible to put testing and staging behind a vpn but not the production when all 3 are on the same server?

And how do you use a repository to manage the environments?

Development commit to repo, then update testing with repo then rsync staging with testing then rsync prod with staging.. is that good?